# Is there a way to flag the use of non-reentrant C library calls?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, reentrancy

I'm working on a project that's heavily multi-threaded, and was wondering if there's a way to have the compiler flag the use of non-reentrant calls to the C library (e.g. strtok intsead of strtok_r)?  If not, is there a list of calls that are non-reentrant so I can grep through my code base periodically?

A related question is if there's a way to flag 3d party library use of non-reentrant calls.

I'm assuming reentrancy implies thread-safety, but not necessarily the other way around.  Is there a good reason to use non-reentrant calls in a threaded project?

Comment: Question - are all C runtime calls in Linux that maintain state between calls (e.g. malloc, rand, strtok, etc...) inherently non-threadsafe?  Or is there a compiler/linker directive to specify linking with a thread safe version for these calls?  I'm actually wondering if there's really a problem to be solved for thread safety.

Comment: @selbie: No, it varies. For instance, [malloc](http://www.bozemanpass.com/info/linux/malloc/Linux_Heap_Contention.html) is generally threadsafe. The threadsafety of `rand()` is a philosophical question anyway. A perfect `rand` implementation (an oracle) would inherently be threadsafe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For source, you could possibly insist that every source file contains the line:

```
#include <beware.h>
```

after the C headers, and then the `beware.h` header file contains:

```
#define strtok   unsafe_function_call_detected_strtok
#define getenv   unsafe_function_call_detected_getenv
```

or some other suitable set of names that are unlikely to be real functions. That will result in compilation and/or linker errors.

For libraries, it's a bit more difficult. You can look into using `nm` to extract all the unresolved names in each object file and ensure none of the unsafe ones are called.

This wouldn't be the compiler doing it but it would be easy enough to incorporate into the build scripts. See the following transcript:

```
$ cat qq.c
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
        printf ("Hello, world.\n");
        return 0;
    }

$ gcc -c -o qq.o qq.c

$ nm qq.o
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 r .rdata
00000000 t .text
         U ___main
00000000 T _main
         U _puts
```

You can see the unresolved symbols in that output with a `U` marker (and `gcc` has very sneakily decided to use `puts` instead of `printf` since I gave it a constant string with no formatting commands).

Comment: Good idea on the header file and nm script.  Is there a list of non-reentrant C lib functions somewhere?

Comment: If you're using GCC, you can use `#pragma GCC poison strtok` as a better alternative to the `#define`.

Comment: As a variant on the nm style you can define a file like this:
_checkfns.c_:`void not_thread_safe(); void puts() { not_thread_safe(); }` Then it will hide the system versions of the functions and you'll get an error like: `Undefined symbols: "_not_thread_safe", referenced from: _puts in checkfns.o` if you try to use puts. (You'll need to enable dead code stripping for cases that don't use it though ... `-Xlinker -dead_strip` for me)

Comment: If you use the `#define`, use a name like `unsafe_function_call_detected`, so that the compiler error messages include something that tell you what's actually wrong.

Comment: @Karl: isn't `ooga-booga-wtf` clear enough? :-) No, seriously, that's a good suggestion, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Michael, your idea is interesting, but I can't get it to work.  Let me know if it works for you.  I'm using GCC 4.5.2.

Comment: @suravi It certainly works for me .. I've put the code I use here: https://gist.github.com/1044114 - I'm on OS X using gcc 4.0.1

Comment: @suravi Looks like the linker option to perform dead function stripping is different on your platform (thats the -dead_strip option) You'll need to change that to whatever your platform uses. (man gcc or man ld shoudl find it for you)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look for an equivalent option on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

> is there a list of calls that
>   are non-reentrant so I can grep
>   through my code base periodically?

I looked through the GNU libc function list, and picked out the ones with _r.  Here's the list.

asctime, crypt, ctime, drand48, ecvt, encrypt, erand48, fcvt, fgetgrent, fgetpwent, getdate, getgrent, getgrgid, getgrnam, gethostbyaddr, gethostbyname2, gethostbyname, getmntent, getnetgrent, getpwent, getpwnam, getpwuid, getutent, getutid, getutline, gmtime, hcreate, hdestroy, hsearch, initstate, jrand48, lcong48, lgamma, lgammaf, lgammal, localtime, lrand48, mrand48, nrand48, ptsname, qecvt, qfcvt, rand, random, readdir64, readdir, seed48, setkey, setstate, srand48, srandom, strerror, strtok, tmpnam, ttyname

Comment: Note on `readdir_r`: check out the manpage. GNU libc recommends to use the regular `readdir` and deprecate `readdir_r`

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the second part of your question:

Non re-entrant calls *may* be implemented in a way that gives them a performance advantage. In this case if you know you're only making those calls from one thread (or within one critical section), and they're your bottleneck then choosing the non-reentrant call makes sense. But I'd only do it if there were performance measurements suggesting that it was critical to do so... And carefully document it..

Answer (score 0):

For binaries, you can use `LD_PRELOAD` to intercept whatever C library functions you like and take whatever action you want (abort, log an error but proceed, etc.)

During development, you can also use valgrind to do the same.

For some sample code and references, see the answers to [how could I intercept linux sys calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69859/how-could-i-intercept-linux-sys-calls)

Answer (score 0):

[Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) will flag use of non-reentrant standard library functions.  Enable the *portability* warnings to enable this check.

Refer to [`non_reentrant_functions_list` in checknonreentrantfunctions.h](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/blob/master/lib/checknonreentrantfunctions.h#L65) for a list of the functions Cppcheck will flag.

Example of the message Cppcheck will emit:

> Non reentrant function 'strtok' called. For threadsafe applications it is recommended to use the reentrant replacement function 'strtok_r'. (portability: nonreentrantFunctionsstrtok)

Comment: The list of functions that are checked appears incomplete. strerror_r() is missing. There are also other functions (without _r suffix) that are not reentrant, such as getenv(), system(), and whole bunch of others. List here: [http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_01]. But even that isn't complete. Think about setlocale() or any other function that modifies a process-wide attribute. You can't call those from threaded libraries without potentially causing havoc.