# How to make static linked ELF file to load LD_PRELOAD .so

Tags: linux, loader, elf, ld-preload

I have static linked binary (ELF file) it doesn't have dynamic segment, .dymsym sections and it doesn't perform LD_PRELOAD command and etc.
How could i create fake dummy dynamic segment to activate dynamic loader and perform LD_PRELOAD command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a statically linked elf binary to dynamically linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976680/convert-a-statically-linked-elf-binary-to-dynamically-linked)

Comment: Uhh I've read this question and your previous question, could you please post some code of yours and explain to me what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How could i create fake dummy dynamic segment to activate dynamic loader and perform LD_PRELOAD command?

You can't.

Even if you could, getting `LD_PRELOAD` to preload something would *still* be useless: usually you want to interpose some symbols in your `LD_PRELOAD`ed library, but that requires these symbols to be *unresolved* in the main binary, or at least exported in its dynamic symbol table. A statically linked executable *doesn't have* any unresolved symbols, nor a dynamic symbol table by definition.

Comment: Interposition is not the only reason to use LD_PRELOAD - the preloaded dll can create threads that perform various tasks (monitoring, profiling or others). I was unpleasantly surprised to discover this isn't possible for statically linked elfs.

Answer (score 0):

I will start by saying that I don't think that your proposed solution works, but there is a way load dynamic libraries into static binaries (which answers tyour initial question).

> How to make static linked ELF file to load LD_PRELOAD .so

To do such you will need to call the linker directly such as ld.so (exactly the same as calling a normal executable). If you are not finding it, check for the following paths:

```
ls /lib64/ld*
ls /lib/ld*
```

You shloud find a linker for x86(32bits) and 64bits. Choose the one compatible with binary you want to inject. In fact you can also use `--help` to show some of the options. The last part is calling the loader with the `--preload` option and the executable, like this:

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --preload /path/to/shared_lib.so /path/to/executable
```

You might want to check ld.so manpages as well.

NOTE: This will not replace the symbols on the binary (aka replacing with the injected implementation), however this can be useful for enabling restrictions on the process with things like SECCOMP or Landlock LSM.

Comment: How do you actually execute any code in a library preloaded in this way? `__attribute_((constructor))` does not seem to work; anything else I'm missing?