# How to efficiently determine application generating packets

Tags: python, network-programming, cpu-usage, scapy

While working on a research project, I have been able to semi-successfully match outbound packets to their source application by running psutil's get_connections and matching remote addresses with a packet's IP destination in scapy (python).  The object is to recognize the source app of all outbound packets and run them through a security check.  Unfortunately, it seems that get_connections has an extremely high CPU usage.  Running `top` while my scripts work reveals python taking up between 30 and 100.5 percent of CPU consistently (well, the latter only for a brief moment).  Is there a better (more efficient) way to determine what app is generating packets?  If not directly, is there a more efficient way to match established connections to applications?

Comment: Assuming Linux, the most efficient way would be to [intercept the system calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69859/how-could-i-intercept-linux-sys-calls), although it may be overkill depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You can probably do this with [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) or [AppArmor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor), so you should probably take a look at those before writing your own solution.

Comment: Okay. You probably ought to include any constraints like that in the original question, including the protocol by which the local system communicates with said "external switch".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Hone Project -
https://github.com/HoneProject/Linux-Sensor

Comment: Thanks.  If this is reliable, it will probably do the trick! :)

Comment: It seems like it will.  I got it installed, and everything is just what I'm looking for.  Now to work on somehow reading in all the extra headers from the device it creates. :P

Comment: Awesome. Enjoy! Hope you can post what research it is for.