# LD_PRELOAD does not work as expected

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, ld, ld-preload

Consider the following library which can be preloaded before any program execution:

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -shared -fPIC preload.cpp -o preload.so
// LD_PRELOAD=./preload.so <command>
#include <iostream>

struct Goodbye {
    Goodbye() {std::cout << "Hello\n";}
    ~Goodbye() {std::cout << "Goodbye!\n";}
} goodbye;
```

The problem is that, while the constructor of the global variable `goodbye` is always called, the destructor is not called for some programs, like `ls`:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./preload.so ls
Hello
```

For some other programs, the destructor is called as expected:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./preload.so man
Hello
What manual page do you want?
Goodbye!
```

Can you explain why the destructor is not called in the first case?
EDIT: the above question has been already answered, that is a program might well use _exit(), abort() to exit.

However:

**Is there a way to force a given function being called when a preloaded program exits?**

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204608) seems to indicate that the destructor should *always* be called. Can you do some more research to narrow down what types of programs end up calling the destructor and which ones do not?

Comment: What do you mean by "type"? I cannot seem to find a way to distinguish "good" programs from "evil" programs. Note that the problem happens also when the return code is 0 (no error, no abort())

Comment: Try writing a preload module in C, using GCC's `__attribute__((constructor))` to run a function on startup; have that function use `atexit` to register a function to run on teardown.  Does that behave differently?  (It *shouldn't*, but it might.)

Comment: Also, since we are in "potential implementation bug" territory here, it would be very helpful to know the OS, and the exact version of GCC and of the C library.

Comment: R.. has answered your second question but *not* your first question.  It is *not* possible to force a function to be called no matter what, because of `_exit` and `abort` and various other "abnormal program termination" mechanisms whose contract includes that they *don't* execute any destructors, `atexit` functions, etc.  However, I find it implausible that `/bin/ls` would normally exit that way, so there is still a mystery as to why your preload module's destructor isn't getting run.

Comment: @Martin OK, in that case edit the output of `g++ --version` and of `/lib/ld-linux.so.2 $(find /lib -name libc.so.6 -print | head -1)` into the question.  DO NOT attempt to remove any apparently irrelevant information from the output of these commands.

Comment: Note that you are using fairly high-level functionality here: `std::cout` is a buffering stream that is synchronized with the stdio streams. It may well be that `ls` does something at exit that disrupts this mechanism. What happens if you use `::write(2, "Goodbye\n", 8);` instead?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`ls` has `atexit (close_stdout);` as its initialisation code. When it finishes, it closes stdout (i.e. `close(1)`), so your `cout`, `printf` or `write(1, ...` operations will not print anything. It doesn't mean destructor isn't called. You can verify this by e.g. creating a new file in your destructor.

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c#n1285 here is the line in GNU coreutils ls.

It is not just `ls`, most of coreutils do that. Unfortunately, I don't know exact reason *why* they prefer to close it.

Side note on how this could be found (or at least what I did) - may help next time or with program with no source code access:

Destructor message is printed with `/bin/true` (simplest program I could think of), but isn't printed with `ls` or `df`. I started with `strace /bin/true` and `strace /bin/ls` and compared latest system calls. It shown `close(1)` and `close(2)` for `ls`, but none for `true`. After that things started to make sense and I just had to verify that destructor is called.

Comment: Oho!  Would you mind adding a link to the source repository so we can all see this for ourselves?

Comment: I did a little more digging based on your results: it appears that this is done in order to detect write failures on `stdout` before it's too late to exit unsuccessfully.  Unfortunately, the definition of `close_stdout` is hiding over in gnulib, but the comments there are pretty clear: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/closeout.c#n83

Answer (score 9):

If the program exits via `_exit` (POSIX) or `_Exit` (C99) or abnormal program termination (`abort`, fatal signals, etc.) then there's no way destructors could be called. I don't see any way around this.

Comment: Why would `/bin/ls` do that?

Comment: That's a good guess, but http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/ls.c ends in `exit (exit_status);` (OP specified right now he's on linux)

Comment: @Zack, why would `/bin/ls` *not* do that? Unless there are external side-effects required for graceful shutdown (like on-disk data structures need updating or network messages sent to say "bye") why not just `_exit`? There is no need to `free()` the last few blocks if the whole heap is about to go away.

Comment: @Ben I know it looks like just one character of difference, but as a matter of idiom, `_exit` is *unusual*. It's a thing you only use if you have a specific reason you need it. `exit` / return from `main` are the normal way to end a program in C and it would be surprising for a basic utility like `ls` to be abnormal in this way.  Also, if `ls` used `_exit` it would need to manually flush `stdout`.

Comment: @Ben (Note that `exit` does *not* deallocate the `malloc` heap piece by piece.)

Comment: Note to editors: If you're editing an answer to add links to some of the interfaces mentioned, link to authoritative sources like the C standard or at least some sort of C documentation rather than a C++ site.

Answer (score 2):

Like others said, a program might call via `_exit()`, `_Exit()` or `abort()` and your destructors won't even notice. To solve these cases you could override these functions by just writing a wrapper like the following the example below:

```
void
_exit(int status)
{
    void (*real__exit)(int) __attribute__((noreturn));
    const char *errmsg;

    /* Here you should call your "destructor" function. */
    destruct();

    (void)dlerror();
    real__exit = (void(*)(int))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "_exit");
    errmsg = dlerror();
    if (errmsg) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dlsym: _exit: %s\n", errmsg);
        abort();
    }

    real__exit(status);
}
```

But this wouldn't solve all the possibilities of a program escaping without your library's knowledge, because those are not the only exit points an application could have. It could also trigger the `exit` system call via the `syscall()` function and to avoid it you would have to wrap it too.

Another way a program could exit is by receiving an unhandled signal, so you should also handle (or wrap?) all signals that could trigger the death of a program. Read the `signal(2)` man page for more information but please be aware that signals like `SIGKILL` (9) cannot be handled and an application could destroy itself by calling `kill()`. With that being said and unless you don't expect to handle insane applications written by crazy monkeys you should wrap `kill()` too.

Another system call you'd have to wrap is `execve()`.

Anyway, a system call (like `_exit`) could also be triggered directly via an [assembly `int 0x80` instruction](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html) or the obsolete `_syscallX()` **macro**. How'd you wrap it if not from outside the application (like `strace` or `valgrind`)? Well, if you expect this kind of behaviour in you programs I suggest you drop the `LD_PRELOAD` technique and start thinking about doing like `strace` and `valgrind` do (using `ptrace()` from another process) or [creating a Linux kernel module to trace it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69859/how-could-i-intercept-linux-sys-calls).

Comment: This is clever, but when programs call `_exit` or `abort` they do it because there's some concrete and compelling reason why destructors, `atexit` functions, and so on *should not* be run.  For instance, on the child side of a `fork`, if `execve` fails, it's critical to use `_exit` so that I/O is not flushed twice.  A library should not be second-guessing the application about that sort of thing.

Comment: ... **no**, the lesson I wanted you to draw from my comment is *not* "you need to wrap `execve` as well", it was "this is the *bad* kind of clever."

Comment: ... **no**? What do you mean by that? Do you think I don't know this is a horrible hack? It's pretty obvious it is ugly. I added `execve` to the list just because I should, not because I didn't understood what you commented.

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain? I'm answering the last question of the OP **AND** giving a minimal and working example.