# How to detect when a certain file has been opened?

Tags: c, linux, file

I am working on a little project in C on Linux and I ran into a problem.
I must make a program that simulates the activity of a WatchDog. So I wrote almost all the code, but I don't know how to do the most important part.
While my app is running in the background, it must detect when certain files are accessed. I have stored in some structures the inode, the path and the name of those files. So, having this info about the files, how can I detect when a process (any process, not a certain one) tries to access one of the files?
Edit: Actually, I must detect the following events: when a file has been opened and when someone tries to modify the file. Like, if a user writes something to a file and then tries to save the changes, I must allow him or not to do that.

Comment: Why not just remove write permissions from the file?

Comment: Never done that but I believe you should do a system call to get all the processes then get the list of handles for each process then get the file name for these handles.

Comment: You need to prevent the write or you need to detect it passively?

Comment: You can use `inotify` to be notified about changes to files. But I don't think you can get notifications about files being opened or read.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you can. There's an `IN_OPEN` event. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html for the documentation of `inotify`

Comment: @Tarik thanks. I found some ways to do that while google-ing for my problem, but I thought there is some other way to do what I want.

Comment: @Barmar sometimes I'll want to prevent it, sometimes I'll allow it. So, I need to detect it passively. I'll check that event. Thanks!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams because in some cases I want to allow the user to make changes to the file.

Comment: I googled out and found that inotify can do the job. @Barmar also mentions it in his comment.

Comment: `inotify` just lets you detect things passively, you can't intercede. To do that you'll would have to be able to control the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for file system watcher. For that  you can use Inotify: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify

Comment: From what I read, it should do it. I'll try it and I'll keep you up to date. Thank you! [can't upvote the answer because I just signed up and I don't have the required reputation]

Comment: Unfortunately the asker needs functionality that inotify cannot provide.

Comment: "if a user writes something to a file and then tries to save the changes, I must allow him or not to do that." That would require you to intercept system calls that open files and write to them. Inotify does not do that indeed.

Comment: By the way, if a user writes to a file, then there is no such a thing as saving his changes. It's already done.

Comment: My answer is not that good. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69859/how-could-i-intercept-linux-sys-calls on how to intercept system calls.