# Intercepting calls to MySQL C API - Linux

Tags: mysql, c, linux

What are the mechanics needed to intercept calls being made from web apps to the MySQL C API in Linux?

I want to be able to intercept SQL calls being made and decide whether they should continue to MySQL.

If anyone point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You didn't even say which OS ... anyway, a trivial but  tedious option is to create a wrapper library.

Comment: Whoops you are absolutely correct! Linux

Comment: Are you going to be able to relink every application that might be making calls to the MySQL system?  Or are you only concerned about those from a particular web server?  Is the DBMS running on the same machine as the web apps?

Comment: only from web server

Comment: You can do this with a wrapper library loaded with LD_PRELOAD. Plenty of examples on the internet, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69859/how-could-i-intercept-linux-sys-calls

Comment: thanks, that is helpful, appreciated