# Can eBPF modify the return value or parameters of a syscall?

Tags: linux, system-calls, bpf, ebpf

To simulate some behavior I would like to attach a probe to a syscall and modify the return value when certain parameters are passed. Alternatively, it would also be enough to modify the parameters of the function before they are processes.

Is this possible with BPF?

Comment: systemtap can do it

Comment: If anyone comes here interested in using eBPF for networking, there is XDP which allows some control over the packets. [Forwarding example](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/bpf/xdp_redirect_kern.c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that attaching eBPF to kprobes/kretprobes gives you read access to function arguments and return values, but that you cannot tamper with them. I am NOT 100% sure; good places to ask for confirmation would be the IO Visor project [mailing list](http://lists.iovisor.org/pipermail/iovisor-dev/) or IRC channel (#iovisor at irc.oftc.net).

As an alternative solution, I know you can at least change the return value of a syscall with [strace](https://strace.io/), with the `-e` option. Quoting [the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html):

> ```
> -e inject=set[:error=errno|:retval=value][:signal=sig][:when=expr]
>        Perform syscall tampering for the specified set of syscalls.
> ```

Also, there was [a presentation](https://fosdem.org/2017/schedule/event/failing_strace/) on this, and fault injection, at Fosdem 2017, if it is of any interest to you. Here is one example command from the slides:

```
strace -P precious.txt -efault=unlink:retval=0 unlink precious.txt
```

**Edit:** As stated by Ben, eBPF on kprobes and tracepoints is definitively read only, for tracing and monitoring use cases. I also got confirmation about this on IRC.

Answer (score 16):

Within kernel probes (kprobes), the eBPF virtual machine has read-only access to the syscall parameters and return value.

However the eBPF program will have a return code of it's own. It is possible to apply a seccomp profile that traps BPF (NOT eBPF; thanks @qeole) return codes and interrupt the system call during execution.

The allowed runtime modifications are:

- `SECCOMP_RET_KILL`: Immediate kill with `SIGSYS`
- `SECCOMP_RET_TRAP`: Send a catchable `SIGSYS`, giving a chance to emulate the syscall
- `SECCOMP_RET_ERRNO`: Force `errno` value
- `SECCOMP_RET_TRACE`: Yield decision to ptracer or set `errno` to `-ENOSYS`
- `SECCOMP_RET_ALLOW`: Allow

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/prctl/seccomp_filter.txt

The `SECCOMP_RET_TRACE` method enables modifying the system call performed, arguments, or return value. This is architecture dependent and modification of mandatory external references may cause an ENOSYS error.

It does so by passing execution up to a waiting userspace ptrace, which has the ability to modify the traced process memory, registers, and file descriptors.

The tracer needs to call ptrace and then waitpid. An example:

```
ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, tracee_pid, 0, PTRACE_O_TRACESECCOMP);
waitpid(tracee_pid, &status, 0);
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html

When `waitpid` returns, depending on the contents of `status`, one can retrieve the seccomp return value using the `PTRACE_GETEVENTMSG` ptrace operation. This will retrieve the seccomp `SECCOMP_RET_DATA` value, which is a 16-bit field set by the BPF program. Example:

```
ptrace(PTRACE_GETEVENTMSG, tracee_pid, 0, &data);
```

Syscall arguments can be modified in memory before continuing operation. You can perform a single syscall entry or exit with the `PTRACE_SYSCALL` step. Syscall return values can be modified in userspace before resuming execution; the underlying program won't be able to see that the syscall return values have been modified.

An example implementation:
[Filter and Modify System Calls with seccomp and ptrace](http://www.alfonsobeato.net/tag/seccomp/)

Comment: Minor correction: seccomp only supports the “classic” version of BPF. There is no support for **e**BPF (“extended BPF”) at this time.

Comment: Updated! Thanks Qeole.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to modify some user space memory using eBPF. As stated in the [bpf.h header file](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/0c0ddd6ae47c9238c18f475bcca675ca74c9dc31/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h):

```
 * int bpf_probe_write_user(void *dst, const void *src, u32 len)
 *  Description
 *      Attempt in a safe way to write *len* bytes from the buffer
 *      *src* to *dst* in memory. It only works for threads that are in
 *      user context, and *dst* must be a valid user space address.
 *
 *      This helper should not be used to implement any kind of
 *      security mechanism because of TOC-TOU attacks, but rather to
 *      debug, divert, and manipulate execution of semi-cooperative
 *      processes.
 *
 *      Keep in mind that this feature is meant for experiments, and it
 *      has a risk of crashing the system and running programs.
 *      Therefore, when an eBPF program using this helper is attached,
 *      a warning including PID and process name is printed to kernel
 *      logs.
 *  Return
 *      0 on success, or a negative error in case of failure.
```

Also, quoting from [the BPF design Q&A](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a2d79c7174aeb43b13020dd53d85a7aefdd9f3e5/Documentation/bpf/bpf_design_QA.rst#q-can-bpf-overwrite-arbitrary-user-memory):

> Tracing BPF programs can overwrite the user memory of the current
> task with bpf_probe_write_user(). Every time such program is loaded
> the kernel will print warning message, so this helper is only useful
> for experiments and prototypes. Tracing BPF programs are root only.

Your eBPF may write data into user space memory locations. Note that you still **cannot** modify kernel structures from within you eBPF program.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to inject errors into a system call invocation using eBPF: https://lwn.net/Articles/740146/

There is a bpf function called `bpf_override_return()`, which can override the return value of an invocation. This is an example using bcc as the front-end: https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/inject.py

According to the [Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html):

> `bpf_override_return()` is only available if the kernel was compiled with the `CONFIG_BPF_KPROBE_OVERRIDE` configuration option, and in this case it only works on functions tagged with `ALLOW_ERROR_INJECTION` in the kernel code.
>
> Also, the helper is only available for the architectures having the `CONFIG_FUNCTION_ERROR_INJECTION` option. As of this writing, x86 architecture is the only one to support this feature.

It is possible to add a function to the error injection framework. More information could be found here: https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/issues/2485

Comment: Thanks! Important caveat, this only works for a small number of whitelisted functions in the kernel.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgSchölly :) I have updated the answer about the white list. But I haven't found the exact default white list for the error injection feature. It seems to support most of the syscall functions in the kernel.

Comment: It looks like it's just a handful of functions, most of them related to the btrfs file system. These functions are annotated with [`ALLOW_ERROR_INJECTION`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?q=ALLOW_ERROR_INJECTION) in the source code.