# ebpf: intercepting function calls

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, bpf, kprobe, ebpf

I am reading about `kprobes` BPF program type, and am wondering if it is possible to not just intercept a function call for tracing purposes or collect some low-level information (registers, stack etc.), but *substitute* a call and execute instead of the actual function?

Does `kprobe` provide this capability or I'm looking at the wrong tool?

Comment: You could also take a look at [Ftrace](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/trace/ftrace-uses.rst) and how it is used in [Livepatch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/livepatch/livepatch.txt) to replace the kernel functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, kprobes BPF programs have only read access to the syscall parameters and return value, they cannot modify registers and therefore **cannot intercept function calls**. This is a limitation imposed by the BPF verifier.

**Kernel modules**, however, can intercept function calls using kprobes.

Comment: thanks for feedback! So I guess https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt is the starting point.

Comment: Yep. You might be interested in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43268462/6884590) too.

Comment: Well, yes, one could change IP register in a kprobe's pre-handler to redirect execution to your function instead of the original one, However, I would also take a look at [Ftrace](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/trace/ftrace-uses.rst), which can also be used to substitute the functions. Perhaps, this could be easier to use, but that is a matter of taste. In fact, [live patching](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/livepatch/livepatch.txt) already does this with Ftrace.

Comment: This is inaccurate today. “uprobes” feature in eBPF doesn’t exactly that.