# How to modify userspace memory using eBPF?

Tags: linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf, bcc-bpf

I'm trying to write a sample code and see how it works practically.

As said [here](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/iovisor-dev/2017-May/000740.html) and [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60484828/11652193).

If everything is correct the output should be:

```
$ cat foo1
this is foo1 content
$ cat foo2
this is foo2 content
$ sudo bcc_mangle_open.py &
[1] 63453
$ cat foo1
this is foo2 content
```

I wrote a sample in BCC, which looks like this:

```py
from bcc import BPF

# define BPF program
prog = """
#include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
int trace_entry(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
    char buf[10];
    char foo2[] = "foo2";
    char *fname = (char *) PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx);

    bpf_probe_read_str(buf, sizeof(buf), fname);
    if (buf[0] != 'f' || buf[1] != 'o' || buf[2] != 'o' || buf[3] != '1') {
        return 0;
    }

    bpf_probe_write_user(fname, foo2, sizeof(foo2));

    return 0;
};
"""

# load BPF program
b = BPF(text=prog)

b.attach_kprobe("do_sys_open", fn_name="trace_entry")
```

The content of `foo1` is supposed to change, but it's not happening.

And I have tried to print `fname` and even `buf` using `bpf_trace_printk()`, but I got nothing in my screen.

Any idea why the content is not changing?

update-1

As suggested by @Queole

.It worked..So we have to give `(char *) PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx)` instead of `(char *) PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx)`. I got the output but a bit weirdly. after some 3-4 `cat foo1`, the content is changing.

```
$ cat foo1
this is foo1 content
$ cat foo1
this is foo1 content
$ cat foo1
this is foo2 content
$ cat foo1
this is foo1 content
$ cat foo1
this is foo1 content
$ cat foo1
this is foo1 content
$ cat foo1
this is foo1 content
$ cat foo1
this is foo1 content
$ cat foo1
this is foo1 content
$ cat foo1
this is foo1 content
$ cat foo1
this is foo1 content
$ cat foo1
this is foo1 content
$ cat foo1
this is foo1 content
$ cat foo1
this is foo1 content
$ cat foo1
this is foo1 content
$ cat foo1
this is foo2 content
```

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Could you check the value returned by `bpf_probe_write_user`? It should be negative in case of error.

Comment: Have you tried reading the second argument instead of the first? It looks like `do_sys_open()` in the kernel gets the file name [in second position](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/open.c?h=v5.7#n1161).

Comment: Thanks..It worked..So we have to give ```(char *) PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx)``` instead of ```(char *) PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx)```. I got the output but a bit weirdly. after some 3-4 ```cat foo1```, the content is changing.

Comment: I have updated the question..Do you know why it's behaving like that?

Comment: I can reproduce. In this case `bpf_probe_write_user()` returns `-EFAULT` (-14) most of the time, indicating that it failed to copy `foo2` to `fname`. I haven't found how to fix that so far.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem too.  I found that the address of param is r--p.  Maybe the param is in .rodata and .data which means it can't be written.  You can try to malloc some mem, copy param to this area and then send this area to the func.

Answer (score 0):

I've been very interested in ebpf lately. And I ran your experiment on Ubuntu 18.04 (5.4.0) and got the same result.
I did not look at the source code of cat. But I wrote a simple cat program, like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char c = '\0';
    int fd;
    char file_name[16];
    memcpy(file_name, "foo1", 4);
    fd = open(file_name, O_RDONLY);
    if(fd < 0)
        return 0;
    while (read(fd, &c, 1) == 1)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

I got what I wanted.
If I chang "`fd = open("file_name", O_RDONLY);`" to "`fd = open("foo1", O_RDONLY);`",  the experiment would fail.